Dynamic column widths of a multicol environment and tcolorbox
I have a tcolorbox whose contents are in a multicol layout; they are some paragraghs of text followed by two or three tcolorboxes. Here is a simplified version of my code:
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
     
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=red, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \LARGE\textbf{CORE SYSTEM}
        \normalsize\\{
            \Large\textbf{VENGEANCE OF GAIA}
            \\
            \normalsize\textit{Hounded by enemies superior in numbers and technology, the Hercynian people have learned to rely on maximum exploitation of advantageous terrain and the element of surprise as force multipliers. When encroaching on their land, every bush has ears, and every glint in the jungle canopy might be the lens of a scope trained on its target.}

\begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=green, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
            \textbf{Conceal Position}\\
            \normalsize{ Passive, Free Action }\\
            At the end of its turn, if it hasn't made any \textbf{Attacks} or forced any \textbf{Saves}, the Antlion can \textbf{Hide} as a \textbf{free action}.
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=orange, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
            \textbf{Decapitating Strike}\\
            \normalsize{ Active (1CP), Protocol, Efficient }\\
            This action can only be taken while \textbf{Hidden}. Your next \textbf{Weapon Attack} before the start of your next turn gains +1d3 \textbf{bonus damage} for every \textbf{Accuracy} {+} \textbf{Die} which affects the final roll.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    }
    \end{multicols}
                        
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

Normally, they end up like this:

Note that some of the left column is still empty; this is what I want to avoid, for either column.
What I want to achieve is, without having to manually set the width of the columns, have it change so that if there is too little text to cover the whole left column, the left column is shrunk and the right one widened, so it ends up like this:

And if there is too much text, so that the boxes wouldn't cover the whole right column, the left column is widened and the right one shrunk, so it ends up like this:

Is there perhaps a way to measure the height that would be taken up by the text and the inner boxes, and use them as parameters to calculate the necessary widths?

Unrelated, but maybe you want to stop abusing \ for line breaks. Better leave an empty line to start a new paragraph. Then the spacing in the title wouldn't be so wrong.

Thanks. Do you also have any idea how I could go about solving this problem? I already know it's possible to set variables to heghts and widths of things within the document; for example:
\newlength{\imgwidth}
\settowidth{\imgwidth}{\includegraphics{}}
creates a variable equal to the width  will take on the document. Surely something similar can be done for text and tcolorboxes?

I would choose a divided tcolorbox with sidebyside layout and then just manually adjust the width of one of the sides. If you only have one such box, adjusting it once isn't much trouble. If you have many such boxes, the document will look very chaotic if the widths differ in every box.

Setting thw widths manually is precisely what I need not to do: I'm trying to make a script that takes files from game mods (in JSON format) and automatically makes pages of a manual in PDF format that look just like the manual for the official game.
The Official manual goes to great pains never to leave blank spaces in a page, to the point that even lore entries for items are made longer or shorter for the only reason f making sure that the lore and the game statistics together take up the whole page.
Having vaired widths of columns might look chaotic, but it's the style I must imitate.

This uses saveboxes to measure the heights and iterates until the two heights are within 1ex of each other.
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    
    \newif\ifdone
     
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=red, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
\def\leftwidth{0.5\linewidth}
\loop
    \sbox1{\begin{minipage}[b]{\leftwidth}
        \LARGE\textbf{CORE SYSTEM}
        \par\normalsize
            \Large\textbf{VENGEANCE OF GAIA}
        \par\normalsize\textit{Hounded by enemies superior in numbers and technology, the Hercynian people have learned to rely on maximum exploitation of advantageous terrain and the element of surprise as force multipliers. When encroaching on their land, every bush has ears, and every glint in the jungle canopy might be the lens of a scope trained on its target.}
   \end{minipage}}%
\sbox3{\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\leftwidth-\columnsep}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=green, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
            \textbf{Conceal Position}\\
            \normalsize{ Passive, Free Action }\\
            At the end of its turn, if it hasn't made any \textbf{Attacks} or forced any \textbf{Saves}, the Antlion can \textbf{Hide} as a \textbf{free action}.
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=orange, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
            \textbf{Decapitating Strike}\\
            \normalsize{ Active (1CP), Protocol, Efficient }\\
            This action can only be taken while \textbf{Hidden}. Your next \textbf{Weapon Attack} before the start of your next turn gains +1d3 \textbf{bonus damage} for every \textbf{Accuracy} {+} \textbf{Die} which affects the final roll.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \hrule height0pt% bottom bseline
    \end{minipage}}%
\ifdim\ht1>\ht3\relax
  \ifdim 1ex>\dimexpr \ht1-\ht3\relax
    \donetrue
  \fi
\else
  \ifdim 1ex>\dimexpr \ht3-\ht1\relax
    \donetrue
  \fi
\fi
\ifdone\else
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\leftwidth}{\wd1+(\ht1-\ht3)/(\ht1+\ht3)*\wd1}%
\repeat

\noindent\usebox1\hfill\usebox3

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



I wish I could tell you if this works for me, but with the Free Plan on Overleaf I don't have enough compile time to properly compile it. Could you point me to the most accessible tutorial you know for using TeXstudio? I've installed both it and texlive 2024 both the formaer doesn't "see" the latter.

Sorry, I use TexnicCenter and MikTeX.
